# How to develop Equanimity or Upeksha?

Tags: reference-request, sutras, equanimity

Namo Buddhaya.

[This sutta](https://suttacentral.net/sn46.26/en/bodhi) asks for development of 7 factors of enlightenment including Mindfulness and Equanimity. Development of Mindfulness is described in detail but I couldn't find any sutta describing development of Equanimity.

My question is : Can you please suggest a sutta which describes how to develop Equanimity ?

Comment: I guess Cariyapitaka has a story on equanimity but I am unable to find it on the internet.

Comment: The Cariyapitaka  is [here](https://suttacentral.net/cp) but not translated, only Pali and Vietnamese.

Comment: @ChrisW Does anybody know Pali? [This](https://suttacentral.net/cp35/pli/ms) is the target Sutta which I want translated.

Comment: This question may be a duplicate of [Can anyone please translate a sutta from Pali to English?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/25985/254)

Comment: @ChrisW Yes. I posted that question so that everyone can be aware of the problem. Here I had asked you individually.

Comment: Actually I don't know whether it is a duplicate unless the Sutta is translated into English.

Comment: @ChrisW I will close one of the questions as soon as I get relevant reply to any one of them.