# Can you translate, from Pali, this sutta about Equanimity?

Tags: pali-canon, sutras, translation

I have been trying to find out the meaning and nature of Equanimity or Upeksha.

I came across this Sutta which says something about Equanimity but it is in Pali.

- [Mahālomahaṃsacariya](https://suttacentral.net/cp35) (Cp 35, i.e. number 35 in the [Cariyāpiṭaka](https://suttacentral.net/cp35/pli/ms))

Can anyone please translate this Sutta from Pali to English ?

Comment: This is not a sutta spoken by the Buddha: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cariyapitaka.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Pali is:

> Susāne seyyaṃ kappemi,  Chavaṭṭhikaṃ upanidhāyahaṃ;  Gāmaṇḍalā
>   upāgantvā,  Rūpaṃ dassentinappakaṃ.
>
> Apare gandhamālañca,  bhojanaṃ vividhaṃ bahuṃ;  Upāyanānūpanenti, 
>   haṭṭhā saṃviggamānasā.
>
> Ye me dukkhaṃ upaharanti
>
> Whatever difficulty presents itself
>
> ye ca denti sukhaṃ mama;
>
> Whatever comforts he is offered/Whatever happiness he offers (?)
>
> Sabbesaṃ samako homi
>
> Always/everywhere existing (with) the same (calmness)
>
> dayā kopo na vijjati.
>
> Kindness but no irritation is found
>
> Sukhadukkhe tulābhūto
>
> Remaining/existing/being balanced in pleasure, pain [feelings]
>
> Yasesu ayasesu ca
>
> Fame/success & obscurity
>
> Sabbattha samako homi
>
> Always/everywhere existing (with) the same (calmness)
>
> Esā me upekkhāpāramī”ti.
>
> That is perfect equanimity
>
> https://suttacentral.net/cp35/pli/ms

Click on the Sutta Central link; then click on the cog wheel at the top right; active the Pali-English function; highlight the Pali & try to do the translation for yourself.

[image]

Comment: I have got to thank you for showing me the way.